# Normalization using R

Tags: r, normalization, normalize

Hy guys,

I have a table with 1.350.000 rows and 113 columns (samples).
What I want is to normalize all my data the by the smallest sample.

For example:

```
Org samp1   samp2   samp3   samp4   samp5   samp6
A   0.08    4.92    3.34    5.50    2.98    2.99
B   1.97    3.96    4.49    2.79    4.73    4.00
C   4.05    3.99    4.89    3.72    3.83    5.17
D   1.70    5.11    3.97    3.37    2.71    3.22
```

And their corresponding sum.

```
Sum 7.80    17.98   16.69   15.38   14.26   15.37
```

This is the expected table with percentages:

```
Org samp1   samp2   samp3   samp4   samp5   samp6
A   0.01    0.27    0.20    0.36    0.21    0.19
B   0.25    0.22    0.27    0.18    0.33    0.26
C   0.52    0.22    0.29    0.24    0.27    0.34
D   0.22    0.28    0.24    0.22    0.19    0.21
```

And this is the final table:

```
Org samp1   samp2   samp3   samp4   samp5   samp6
A   0.08    2.14    1.56    2.79    1.63    1.52
B   1.97    1.72    2.10    1.42    2.59    2.03
C   4.05    1.73    2.29    1.89    2.10    2.62
D   1.70    2.22    1.85    1.71    1.48    1.63
```

Considering the smallest sum value (samp1 = 7.80). This is the number that I want to use to normalize all the values from all samples.
I know the theory and the first step is to calculate the percentage from each value in the column and after multiply for the smallest value.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: By normalising, do you mean you want the sum of all of the resulting columns to be the same?

Comment: I mean to use the value of the smallest column sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

generate data

```
str <- 'Org samp1   samp2   samp3   samp4   samp5   samp6
A   0.08    4.92    3.34    5.50    2.98    2.99
B   1.97    3.96    4.49    2.79    4.73    4.00
C   4.05    3.99    4.89    3.72    3.83    5.17
D   1.70    5.11    3.97    3.37    2.71    3.22'



file <- textConnection(str)
df <- read.table(file, header = T)
```

get the normalized sum values

```
step1 <- colSums(df[,-1])

step1/min(step1)
```

edit:

to reproduce your example result:

```
step1 <- colSums(df[,-1])

round(df[,-1]/rep(step1,each=nrow(df)),2)

  samp1 samp2 samp3 samp4 samp5 samp6
1  0.01  0.27  0.20  0.36  0.21  0.19
2  0.25  0.22  0.27  0.18  0.33  0.26
3  0.52  0.22  0.29  0.24  0.27  0.34
4  0.22  0.28  0.24  0.22  0.19  0.21

round(df[,-1]/rep(step1,each=nrow(df)) * min(step1),2)

  samp1 samp2 samp3 samp4 samp5 samp6
1  0.08  2.13  1.56  2.79  1.63  1.52
2  1.97  1.72  2.10  1.41  2.59  2.03
3  4.05  1.73  2.29  1.89  2.10  2.62
4  1.70  2.22  1.86  1.71  1.48  1.63
```